# Can I have 2 index within a single dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm working with computer simulation and I use a lot of variables that change from one simulation to another. I have to run short but numerous simulation (like 1000+) so keeping track of these is important.

Up until now, I was simply adding a new columns with the data inside. So my data would look something like.

```
DataX, DataY, DataZ, variable1, variable2, variable3, ....
```

So I was basically making 1 column per variable.

Every time I would need to get new variables I would add them as a new column.

Not effective but at least everything was within the same file which was quite handy tbh.

My internship at my lab is about to end and my tutor asked me to clear up the code and make it so that anyone could keep using it.

The thing is, each of these variable also have 2 further sub variable.

So I made a new function that gather all those variables and make a neat little dataframe which looks like this

```
Parameter    Value    Lambda    Mod
temperature  10       1         0
VarE         1.5      5         0.5
```

etc

To make it easily accessible I also turned Parameter as the index so I can use df_param.loc['VarE','Value'] for instance

However because of that, they're not all within the same file. Which isn't handy.
Since they'll have to use above 1000+ data file when plotting, and have to filter everything, having the parameter separated from the data can lead to mistakes (which isn't possible atm since everything is within the same file).

If I convert back "parameter" as a column, I can easily do that

Index  DataX, DataY, DataZ,  Parameter, Value, Lambda, Mod

The issue I have (mostly from a practical stand point) is that since parameter isn't the index anymore, I can't do  df_param.loc['VarE','Value']  anymore. I would need to know at exactly what index 'VarE' is and do df.param.loc['index','value'] and with well over 15 parameter to pick from, it's a bit sketchy.

Basically, is there a way to have 2 index? like
One index for DataX, DataY, DataZ (let's call it 'dt') and one for Value Lambda and Mod which would be 'Parameter'

So two df within one basically.

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you familiar with the notion of multi-index? Is it relevant for your case?

Comment: I am not, and after a quick google search on "multi-index" I think this is exactly what I need, gonna check this out and come back for more question if i can't figure out how to make it work. But it does seem exactly to be what I need (I don't know how I missed that... I suppose I need to change the bing by default at some point)

Ty for the quick answer